# Java String search design with mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table with a column "Products" with more than 100k records.

Products column will have String data.

I want to search ProductName1 from the table.. I guess using query with %LIKE% will take a long time.

Can anyone suggest any design pattern/sql optimization techniques? Using java for API and MYSQL database.

Comment: No design pattern.  If the row has a lot of records, and you have a specific column that is searched frequently, then index it that way search is faster.   You need to consider as well, if it is important that you search by %LIKE% or %EQUALS% is sufficient.  If EQUALS, then once it reaches a match, it stops searching, unlike the other.

Comment: @SMA. Thank you for response, I want to do exact search. Only indexing will be sufficient?

Comment: It should be @ABC